# Facebook Graph API; different behavior on simulator and device

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ipad

I developed a game for iPad using SDK 4.2. I am using latest Facebook Graph API to publish score on Facebook wall but have disabled opening Safari for authentication by changing in method:

```
- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth
                safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth {
   trySafariAuth = YES; //changed to 
   trySafariAuth = NO;
}
```

It works well on Simulator by opening login dialog inside the app but on device (iPad) it opens Safari and the application goes in the background. While tracing through debugger, I found that:

```
didOpenOtherApp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbAppUrl]];
```

in the same method is 'YES' when run on device and 'NO' when run on simulator. This difference is causing difference in behavior. How can it be resolved? I need to use in-app authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. [Here](http://applerr.com/forum/iphone/632/ios-connect-to-facebook-without-leaving-the-app-for-authorization.htm) is the solution.